# When Docker image push on my linux machine unauthorized: authentication required error display

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, open-source, docker-registry

```
unauthorized: authentication required error display.
```

When Docker image push on my linux machine to `dockerHUB`.

Please help me to solve this problem.

reffer following image.

[image]

Comment: Have you run `docker login` first?

Answer (score 0):

you need to run 'docker login' first, like this:

```
wintermute:~ 07:58:23 melgart$ docker login
Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If you don't have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to create one.
Username (melgart):
```

then type in your hub.docker.com credentials when prompted. HTH